# Design repositories following the DDD concepts

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, domain-driven-design

I'm facing a DDD design issue. I'm confused on how to scope/use repositories with aggregates.

I currently have two aggregates `TecTacClient` and `Entitlement`.

```
public class TecTacClient
{
    (...)
    public ICollection<Entitlement> Entitlements { get; }
    public bool HasActiveEntitlements => Entitlements.Any(x => x.EndDate >= DateTime.Now);

    public TecTacClient((...),IEnumerable<Entitlement> entitlements)
    {
        (...)
        Entitlements = new List<Entitlement>(entitlements ?? Enumerable.Empty<Entitlement>());
    }
}
```

I consider Entitlement as another aggregate. It also holds a collection of entitlement records. Entitlements records are created/updated independently of entitlements. For instance, when I create a booking, I would also create an entitlement record. This operation would not impact the entitlement.

```
public abstract class Entitlement : Entity
{
    (...)

    public ICollection<EntitlementRecord> Records { get; }

    protected Entitlement((...), IEnumerable<EntitlementRecord> records)
    {
        (...)
        Records = new List<EntitlementRecord>(records ?? Enumerable.Empty<EntitlementRecord>());
    }

    public abstract bool IsEligible(Resource resource);
    public DateTimeRange GetCoveringPeriod(DateTime date)  { ... }
    public double GetAvailableQuantity(DateTime date)  { ... }
    public void Consume(DateTime date, double quantity)  { ... }
    public void Match(DateTime date, double quantity)  { ... }
    public void Cancel(int bookingId) { ... }
}
```

I understand that aggregates must be retrieved/persisted using repositories.

Does this mean that I need to create two repositories (for tectacclient and entitlement) and use the entitlement repo whithin the client repo to retrieved entitlements?

Shall I create another repo for EntitlementRecords? Otherwise I end-up having an entitlement repo that looks like this

```
IEntitlementRepo 
{
  void Create(...);
  void Update(...);
  void Delete(...);

  void AddRecord(...);
  void DeleteRecord(...);
}
```

In the end, in the DDD world do I need to introduce dependencies between repositories to retrieve/persist my aggregates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One repository per aggregate is simple and good solution, so it's better to have one repo for Entitlements and another for EntitlementRecords.

By the way, your TecTacClient aggregate does't look well-designed. Normally it should not contain Entitlement aggregates. Or Entitlement should not be considered as separate aggregate, it should be a part of TecTacClient aggregate. The same is for EntitlementRecord: it should be considered as part of Entitlement aggregate or Entitlement should not contain it.
Read more about "[Design Small Aggregates](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2020371&seqNum=3)" rule.

Comment: I thought that one of the goals of the DDD approach was to group entities within an aggregate to make models richer and systems simpler. But now after reading this article, I feel like entities that need to be persisted must be associated to their own aggregates. In my situation, by removing the relationships between client, entitlement and record I have the feeling that I'm moving to a anemic design (1 entity, 1 aggregate, not much logic)

Comment: You say "anemic design" like it's a bad thing :) The design choices should be based on knowledge of domain, so I can't make these choises for you... Look at sample projects, usually Client is one aggregate, and Order with its OrderItems is another. It can be translated to your domain: TecTacClient is one aggregate, and Entitlement with its records is another. About logiс: in my opinion aggregates should not contain a lot of logic, only logic about consistence of aggregate itself.

Comment: Very interesting. Where do you store the business logic if it's not in the aggregate?

Comment: Most logic resides in 1) domain services and 2) internal domain layer objects (which not exposed to application layer).